# Custom dynamic CSS for Aurelia applications

Tags: css, aurelia

I'm trying to make a white-label website that can have the title and CSS theming altered based on the domain name accessing the website.  I haven't been able to figure out the best way to insert custom theming CSS dynamically into the entire Aurelia application.  I'd like to allow organizations to change the primary and secondary theme colors and their icon image and have that applied to the Aurelia application based on the domain name that they use to access the application.  I'd like to be able to store these values in a database and create the CSS dynamically so it will change the theming as they make changes to the color/logo values.

Suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might actually be easier to handle on the server depending on how you're delivering the initial index.html page. You could instead make this index.php|aspx|js and dynamically include the correct stylesheet import depending on the domain.

Comment: What about using [Aurelia PAL](https://github.com/aurelia/pal/blob/master/src/index.js#L273) and the 
  `injectStyles(styles: string, destination?: Element, prepend?:boolean)` method?  I can setup a server-based dynamic index.html|php|..., but I was hoping to keep the website static and only handle the REST API on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using CSS Variables for this https://jonathan-harrell.com/live-theming-with-css-variables/

Basically, use CSS Variables in your CSS file and then

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--background`, value);
```

Comment: Where do you set this properties? is there a good place to define this once per APP?